# WebSocket Connection establishment from Browser

Tags: web, websocket

The question is regarding Web Socket connection establishment procedure.

from RFC 6455 , i understand that WebSocket technology was developed for browser based applications to establish full duplex TCP connection with the server.

My questions,

1. So when we Say browser based , the only way to establish web Socket connection is using javaScripts? i.e all browser based clients can establish webSocket connection using JS?
2. Can we use the WebSockets URL to render webPage on the borwser? Does browsers supports?

   Like  typing ws://www.sample.com/login in the address bar will display login page?
   Does browser understands "ws" as protocol and establishes connection and display the page?

So for my question2 i understand as, to establish a WebSocket connection from Browser, We should already have a webPage and logic in that webPage will establish the WebSocket connection. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Thanks
Pradeep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the WebSocket API, the client-side code must be JavaScript, yes. The server-side code can pretty much be whatever language you want.

To answer your other question, the WebSocket protocols (both ws and wss) cannot be used to load a web page directly. The WebSocket protocols can only be used to establish a connection with a server-side script, which upon a successful handshake, will upgrade the HTTP connection to a WebSocket connection to reduce the headers sent between the client and server.

So, yes, in general, you should already have a web page coded separately, and then add the WebSocket logic on top of that to establish a socket connection with the server as necessary.

Comment: Thanks Hartley. Your answer clarifies my doubt :). will get back if got some other question on WebSockets